# Submitting data from text box to Firebase not working

Tags: javascript, html, submit, firebase

I have this text box in HTML:

```
    <script src="../js/writeTo.js"></script>
    <form>
        <div class="post-title">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Post Title">
        </div>
        <div class="post-content">
            <textarea type="text" placeholder="Post Content"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

and my js file called writeTo.js contains this code:

```
    var url = "https://blog-posts.firebaseio.com/";

    var firebaseRef = new Firebase(url);


    function funct1()

    {
var title = $('#post-title').val();

     var post = $('#post-content').val();

     var date = Date();

     firebaseRef.set({Title: +title, Content: +post, Date: +Date()});

    }



    submit.onclick = funct1();
```

When I type something in my text box and click submit, I look at my Firebase and there is no new data (I'm also new to using Firebase).

It does not work, can anyone see the problem? (There are probably a few, I am new to JavaScript)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few problems with your script. I've solved them in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frankvanpuffelen/43trG/), but will also explain below.

### Getting the text content of your inputs

Your HTML for the inputs looks like this:

```
<div class="post-title">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Post Title">
</div>
```

The JavaScript you use to read the value is:

```
var title = $('#post-title').val();
```

If you read [the documentation for `val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), you'll see that it is meant to be invoked on the `input` element itself. You are invoking it on the wrapping `div`.

The simplest change is to get the value like this:

```
var title = $('#post-title').text();
```

### Associating the handler with the form

You hook up your event handler with the form like this:

```
submit.onclick = funct1();
```

Unfortunately this will not work as you expect it to.

What is does is:

1. Invoke `funct1`
2. Assign the return value of `funct1` to `onclick`

What you instead want to do is:

```
submit.onclick = funct1;
```

So this will assign `funct1` to `onclick`.

You might want to read up on more modern approaches of assigning event handlers btw.

### Passing the values to Firebase

Your code for passing the values to Firebase seems a bit off. Use this instead

```
 firebaseRef.set({Title: title, Content: post, Date: date});
```

### Cancel the regular browser handling of the form submit

The browser normally handles clicks on a form's submit button by posting the form's values to a URL.

But in your application you are handling this yourself, so you should tell the browser to ignore the submit.

You can do this by returning `false` from your function:

```
 return false;
```

Note that this will give the following warning in Chrome:

> event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

So you should indeed consider using [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) instead of returning false. See the total code below for how to do that.

## Complete code

```
var url = "https://blog-posts.firebaseio.com/";

var firebaseRef = new Firebase(url);

function funct1(evt)
{
  var title = $('#post-title').text();

  var post = $('#post-content').text();

  var date = Date();

  firebaseRef.set({Title: title, Content: post, Date: date});
  evt.preventDefault();
}

var submit = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

submit.onclick = funct1;
```

### Adding a new post, instead of overwriting the existing one

Your code will now replace the blog post that lives at your Firebase. I imagine that you'll probably prefer to add a new post, when pressing the submit button.

To accomplish this, you'll need to call Firebase's `push` function. Firebase has some great documentation on [managing lists](https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-lists.html).

The gist of it is this though:

```
var postRef = firebaseRef.push(); // create a new post
postRef.set({Title: title, Content: post, Date: date});
```

So you create a new post and then set your values on that, instead of on the top-level Firebase ref.

Comment: Thank you event.preventDefault() help me fix my form submit issue!

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen I ran your code and it says Uncaught ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined What did I do wrong? I've included firebase scripts